# AWS Quicksight KPI Order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

Hopefully I am missing something simple. I am using a KPI to show a current month's value compared to the previous month (with the difference in the middle). By default it April in the top right and May in the top left. I wish to swap positions. If I change the order the difference value inverts, so it appears that AWS always wants to calculate right to left. Can this be changed?